# Find the element common in all the arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have multiple arrays and I have to find the element common in all the arrays. For example, I am having 5 arrays as follows:

```
var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var array2 = ['B', 'C', 'E'];
var array3 = ['B', 'C', 'Z'];
var array4 = ['C'];
var array5 = ['A','C'];
```

I have to get the **C** as the output as it is the only element common in all the 5 arrays.

```
output = ['C'] ;
```

Is it possible to achieve this in typescript? Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: You need to create multiple `for` loops to do so!

Comment: try higher order filter function

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tkekgk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nested filter

```
const Commonvalue=array1.filter(value => -1 !== array2.indexOf(value)).filter(value => -1 !== array3.indexOf(value)).filter(value => -1 !== array4.indexOf(value)).filter(value => -1 !== array5.indexOf(value));
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tkekgk

Comment: Thanks Chellappan for providing the solution and help me out. This perfectly matches my requirement.